# Adding thick lines between dots using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

How do I add the thick light coloured, grey line between the dots, as shown in the picture?

[image]

I have the code for the dots themselves:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
 \fill[xshift=8cm] foreach \Z [count=\Y] in {7,6,4,3}
  {foreach \X in {1,...,\Z} 
  {(\X,-\Y) circle[radius=3pt]}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please avoid using question titles like "How do I draw this", because "this" has no contextual meaning on its own when people search on the site.

Comment: I guess something like `\draw[gray,line width=6pt](7,4) -- (6,3);\draw[gray,line width=6pt](1,1) -- (3,1);` is in order

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

- `on background layer` is used to put the line drawn beneath the dots. It requires tikz library `backgrounds`.
- `line width=6pt * 0.7` is set in response to `scale=0.7`.

PS: you may want to define nodes in `\fill` for mentioning those dots easier.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
  \fill[xshift=8cm] foreach \Z [count=\Y] in {7,6,4,3} {
    foreach \X in {1,...,\Z} {
      (\X,-\Y) circle[radius=3pt]
    }
  };
  \begin{scope}[on background layer, xshift=8cm]
    \draw[gray!60, line width=6pt * 0.7] (7, -1) -- (6, -2);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]